# How to finish executing $http.get first before running any code in angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-http

I have this method in my service to get a user

```
getUser : function () {
  console.log("get user");
  token = authService.getToken();
  userID = jwtHelper.decodeToken(token);

  console.log(token);
  console.log(userID);

  return $http.get(httpHost + '/users/' + userID).success(function (data) {
     user = data;
     console.log(user);
     return data;
  });
  },
```

I ran this service in .run of angular
Then in my controller I'm getting the data so to present the user's name in my view
`$scope.userName = userService.getFirstName() + " " + userService.getLastName();`.

It will run well most of the time, but there are times that when there is a delay in getting the user the controller will be executed first leaving the $scope.username with undefined values.

How can I make my program to wait for the getUser() to return the user's data first before running the controller??

Comment: Are you sure you want to do that ? Angular works asynchronously, and you're trying to run a synchronous process. Usually, when fetching data, you'd display some pre-loading animation (e.g. throbbers). Then when the data is fetched, you remove the animation and replace it with the actual data. This can be done in pure CSS, or programatically using pure JS or a custom Angular directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$http.get` returns a promise. So what you can do is whenever you call `getUser` is do:

```
service.getUser().then(function(response){ //stuff you need to do on finish here });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to use $q services
.ABCController($scope,$http,$q){
getUser : function () {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  console.log("get user");
  token = authService.getToken();
  userID = jwtHelper.decodeToken(token);

  console.log(token);
  console.log(userID);

  return $http.get(httpHost + '/users/' + userID).success(function (data) {
     user = data;
     console.log(user);
     deferred.resolve(user)
     return deferred.promise;
  });
  },
```

Comment: Is there a reason why just using the `then` function is not sufficient in this case?

Comment: "then" function  is a property of $q(service) I tried using it without defining it it gaved an error.

Comment: Actually, it's not. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http Look at the return value. `then` is a function included with an HttpPromise. You must have something else going on, because `then` works fine for me without including `$q`.

Comment: I have seen a lot of people using then without $q, but I everytime I use it, it gives an error. I have a service.js file and a controller.js The controller calls the service.js which fetches the data and then initialisation of $scope is done in the controller.js